# How to make spiked rather than rectangular columns with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot to display some data. The machine that generates it produces a plot that looks like this. You'll notice each individual blue peak is a spike, with a sharp top.

[image]

I've recreated this with ggplot, but is there a way to get geom_col, or another function, to produce a spike for each peak?

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(rpt = c(100.803333333333, 101.783333333333, 102.733333333333, 103.653333333333, 
                           104.64, 105.566666666667, 106.526666666667, 107.46, 108.36, 109.33, 
                           110.303333333333, 111.276666666667, 112.223333333333, 113.136666666667, 
                           114.186666666667, 115.21, 116.2, 117.153333333333, 118.18, 119.17, 
                           120.16, 121.153333333333, 122.163333333333, 123.086666666667, 
                           124.046666666667, 125.003333333333, 125.956666666667, 126.946666666667, 
                           127.866666666667, 128.82, 129.736666666667, 130.7, 131.633333333333, 
                           132.6, 133.573333333333, 134.51, 135.453333333333, 136.43, 137.376666666667, 
                           138.356666666667, 139.306666666667, 140.256666666667, 141.213333333333, 
                           142.166666666667, 143.16, 144.086666666667, 145.046666666667, 
                           146.01, 147.013333333333, 147.946666666667, 148.913333333333, 
                           149.853333333333, 150.86, 151.803333333333, 152.746666666667, 
                           153.693333333333, 154.673333333333, 155.66, 156.576666666667, 
                           157.53, 158.486666666667, 159.443333333333, 160.403333333333, 
                           161.403333333333, 162.33, 164.223333333333, 165.226666666667, 
                           166.123333333333, 167.023333333333, 168.103333333333, 168.936666666667, 
                           170.026666666667, 170.9, 171.85, 172.62, 173.61, 174.716666666667, 
                           175.713333333333, 176.64, 177.57, 178.466666666667, 180.913333333333, 
                           181.256666666667, 182.286666666667, 183.32, 184.283333333333, 
                           185.246666666667, 186.136666666667, 187.146666666667, 188.16, 
                           188.823333333333, 190.036666666667, 190.983333333333, 191.613333333333, 
                           191.93, 192.323333333333, 192.84, 193.91, 194.866666666667, 195.706666666667, 
                           199.523333333333, 200.563333333333, 201.326666666667, 202.293333333333, 
                           203.346666666667, 204.893333333333, 206.943333333333, 208.223333333333, 
                           208.846666666667, 209.68, 210.723333333333, 211.476666666667, 
                           212.023333333333, 212.363333333333, 214.71, 216.576666666667, 
                           216.97, 219.883333333333, 221.806666666667, 222.62, 223.526666666667, 
                           224.436666666667, 225.35, 226.273333333333, 227.056666666667, 
                           228.22, 229.013333333333, 232.076666666667, 238.52, 240.806666666667, 
                           245.48, 248.49, 251.136666666667, 256.523333333333, 258.646666666667, 
                           260.856666666667, 265.93, 268.88, 270.963333333333, 283.38, 285.2, 
                           286.223333333333, 288.49, 294.926666666667),
                   height = c(119, 127, 132, 139, 136, 136, 140, 161, 162, 194, 239, 278, 
                              370, 288, 434, 361, 286, 232, 213, 221, 238, 244, 266, 295, 306, 
                              325, 358, 420, 497, 670, 838, 1104, 1451, 1743, 2018, 2170, 2226, 
                              2058, 1777, 1464, 1158, 916, 702, 604, 540, 535, 554, 543, 517, 
                              490, 434, 365, 322, 315, 312, 293, 272, 281, 279, 293, 297, 286, 
                              253, 222, 170, 111, 69, 49, 29, 39, 33, 25, 24, 23, 16, 19, 18, 
                              17, 24, 16, 19, 12, 20, 16, 19, 17, 19, 13, 16, 16, 17, 17, 16, 
                              11, 19, 11, 18, 19, 17, 16, 14, 18, 14, 14, 11, 15, 10, 10, 11, 
                              15, 11, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 10, 12, 10, 15, 14, 24, 27, 30, 22, 
                              11, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 10, 12, 12, 15, 11, 10, 
                              11, 10, 12))
ggplot(data, aes(x=rpt, y=height)) +
  geom_col(position="identity")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach where I add a zero value halfway in between each original value.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  uncount(2, .id = "id") %>%  # repeat each row
  mutate(rpt = if_else(id == 2, (rpt + lead(rpt))/2, rpt),  # space in between 
         height = if_else(id == 2, 0, height)) %>% # zero out every other row
  ggplot(aes(x=rpt, y=height)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]